# Class diagram in CoreIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, uml, class-diagram

In C# OR Java we had to make objects ok different classes and perform composition, inheritance  and polymorphism so we make class diagram based on association between different classes.

But in CodeIgniter where we access all function using url. Neither objects are made nor composition e.t.c is performed. So how I can draw a **Class Diagram** in an application to be developed in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 1):

You can draw the class diagram using [sql workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/) also.
this is an example
[image]

Comment: Thanks but workbench only shows the column names not functions, if i'm not wrong???

Answer (score 0):

if you want to draw them manually (ie. don't want reverse engineering to generate uml from your PHP source), then [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) might be useful (if you're using Windows that is, but since you don't mention it I assume you do).

Comment: Actually Its about my FYP documentation. I have functionality in my mind and no source code. I have drawn use case diagram and activity diagram but now stuck with class diagram.